# Conversion between const wchar_t* and const char*, not allowed using qt

Tags: c++, qt, wchar-t

I am trying to use the library [simplexlsxwriter](https://sourceforge.net/p/simplexlsx/wiki/Home/)  with Qt, however when i try to compile I met the following error on several place in the code :

"cannot convert 'const TCHAR* {aka const wchar_t*}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'size_t strlen(const char*)'"

The line in question is:

```
bool HasZipSuffix(const TCHAR *fn) { 
    const TCHAR *ext = fn+_tcslen(fn);
}
```

In order to remove the error i tried the following:

```
bool HasZipSuffix(const TCHAR *fn) { 
    const char* fn_cc = reinterpret_cast<const char*> (fn);
    const TCHAR *ext = fn+_tcslen(fn_cc );
}
```

It works, however it introduces a lot of errors (about 3720 issues) during compilations. I use mingw53_32 under Qt.

It is very strange since when i create a simple Makefile as follow:

```
ROOT_DIR := ./

CXXFLAGS=-MMD -MP -Wall
CXXFLAGS+= -I$(ROOT_DIR)

src = Zip/zip.cpp \
    Xlsx/Chartsheet.cpp \
    Xlsx/Workbook.cpp \
    Xlsx/Worksheet.cpp \
    Xlsx/XlsxHeaders.cpp \
    main.cpp 

includes = Zip/zip.h \
    tchar.h \
    Xlsx/Chartsheet.h \
    Xlsx/SimpleXlsxDef.h \
    Xlsx/Workbook.h \
    Xlsx/Worksheet.h \
    Xlsx/XlsxHeaders.h

object=$(src:.cpp=.o)

%: %.o
    $(LINK.cpp) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

main: $(object)

-include $(src:.cpp=.d)
```

The compilation encountered absolutely no difficulty and I obtain the desired binary. So my question is, why using Qt the conversion from  const wchar_t* to  const char* throw an error while using "raw" mingw compiler, it does not throw any error ?

Comment: There are functions to actually convert the underlying data, but you can't just reinterpret_cast between things that are different at a binary level.

Comment: I should have not add the reinterpret_cast thing in this question as it is more focused on the reason, why the conversion from `const wchar_t*` to `const char*` does not throw any error using mingw32 (with gcc version 5.3) but it throw an error when I use the same very same compiler using Qt ?

Comment: @SchneiderLoïc: Qt is a red herring. It's just a library. You have other compiler flags, most likely.

Answer (score -1):

Just add

```
DEFINES -= UNICODE
```

to the *.pro* file. *qmake* by default defines `-DUNICODE`, which clashes with the *win32* library.